# how can i print all Items with x tag

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 related table in mysql, something like this:

```
Table: Items
Columns: ID, Item_ID, Item_Title, Content

Table: Tags
Columns: Tag_ID, Tag_Title

Table: Items_Tags
Columns: Item_ID, Tag_ID
```

- *Item_ID* is a foreign key in *Items* table.
- *Items_Tags* is a correlation table.

Now i want to print all Items with *x* tag.

for example:

```
// Items
+-----+-----+---------+-----------------+
|  1  | 123 |  tile1  |    content1     |
-----------------------------------------
|  2  | 123 |  tile2  |    content2     |
-----------------------------------------
|  3  | 444 |  tile3  |    content3     |
-----------------------------------------
|  4  | 333 |  tile4  |    content4     |
-----------------------------------------

// Tags
+------+-----+
|  22  | php |
--------------
|  23  | js  |
--------------
|  11  | sql |
--------------

// Item_Tags
+-------+-----+
|  123  | 22  |
---------------
|  444  | 23  |
---------------
|  333  | 11  |
---------------
```

I do not know why I'm confused, just i know that i should use `join`, but how ?!
How can i print all Items with *php* tag ?

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: @JayBlanchard i want to print all items that have the same tag ! how should i do this ?

Comment: the above example is a sample data ? Extend the example with few more data. Single row in each table doesnt help

Comment: Show the work you have tried instead of asking us to do it for you.

Comment: @Makesh i did it ...!

Comment: @JayBlanchard i don't want of you to do it for me, just i want to know how do I communicate between the three related table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join your tables together and then search for the tag title as needed.

```
SELECT * FROM items i 
LEFT JOIN item_tags it ON i.item_id = it.item_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id = it.tag_id
WHERE tag_title = 'x'
```

Comment: Then result will be the first two rows from Items table ?

Comment: Rather than asking, try it. But yes, it will be.

Answer (score 0):

It is usefull for you;

```
SELECT * FROM Items AS I,Tags AS T, Items_Tags AS IT
WHERE I.ID = IT.Item_ID
AND T.ID = IT.Tag_ID
AND WHERE T.Tag_Title = 'x'
```

Comment: This algorithm is optimal? Why don't use `join` ?

Comment: Yes it like join. Simple way :D